# Is there a simple way of showing overflowing text on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have a `p` that may contain long text (I put `overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;`). And I'd like for the text to be shown as a floating link next to the mouse when hovering the paragraph. Is there a native way of doing it or do I have to code a new `div` that gets added when hovering?

Comment: I don't believe that there is a 'native' way of doing that. You might need a combination of `hover` (css), `mouseover` (js), and `mouseout` (js).

Comment: found it I just needed to add `title` to the `p` with the same value as the text

Answer (score 1):

add `title` to the `p` so that when you hover over it it displays it.